# Create Semaphore in PHP linux (Centos)

Tags: php, multithreading, semaphore

I'm using Centos 6.5 with php 5.3.3.

I have two processes that I want to prevent from working together.
I thought about creating a Semaphore so after browsing online I found [this](http://php.net/manual/en/book.sem.php).

This Object doesn't work on my server.
When I call the function **sem_get()**, I get the error:
**"Call to undefined function sem_get()"**

[Read](http://php.net/manual/en/sem.installa) about this too and turns out I need to change some compilations on my server to get it to work.

I made these changes and my server collapsed, **it caused a huge mess** and after restoring the server i'm not going to do that again.

Is there a way to get the above error fixed with a standard include or other solution?

If not, can anyone help me find a way to implement a semaphore in another way or other solution to prevent two process from running at the same time?

I just need a flag to set to true and the other process will check that flag and get out if it is true.

Comment: less screaming please

Comment: Would a SyncMutex (i.e. a named mutex) suffice (or work)?